# Single Row Friendship Database Schema with getting userid from one column or the other

Tags: mysql

I need help querying the friendID from a table.
My table stores the user id of two members who are friends together.

But in order to store a "friendhship" b/w two members I would have to store two records like this:

```
friendshipID |  userID  |  friendID  
1            |  5       |  10
2            |  10      |   5
```

Yet, that seems heavy for the DB when we really only need to store the first record as that is sufficient as it contains both ids of both members.

However, the trouble comes when I want to query the records of the friends of ID=5.  Sometimes the ID is in the userID column and other times it is in the friendID column.

This is the query I am using:

```
SELECT *
FROM friends
WHERE userID = '5'
   OR friendID = '5'
```

But what I want to do is something like this

```
SELECT 
if $userID=5 then userID as myfriend
else friendID=5 then friendID as myfriend
FROM friends WHERE userID='5' OR myfriendID='5'
```

Hope that makes sense.  In the end I would like to have all the friends ID's of member #5 and not bring up results with #5 as the friend or user....but just his friends.

Comment: What language are you using?  Some RDBMs allow for different syntax.

Comment: php.  I guess I should have titled this Friendship Database schema after doing more research.  Looks like there are lots of questions out there about this, but not many answers.  thx

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified which database flavor, php is the language you use to communicate with the database.  Are you using MySql, Oracle, SQL Server, ...?

Comment: THank you once again for this Adma.  Yes, MySQL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This query would return the Id value, and name, of the friends of #5 as shown in this [**SQL Fiddle Example**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0a08f/1/0)

```
SELECT f.FriendId AS FriendId
   , u.Name AS FriendName
FROM FriendTable AS f
INNER JOIN UserAccount AS u ON f.FriendId = u.UserId
WHERE f.UserId = 5

UNION

SELECT f.UserId AS FriendId
   , u.Name AS FriendName
FROM FriendTable AS f
INNER JOIN UserAccount AS u ON f.UserId = u.UserId
WHERE f.FriendId = 5
```

The `UNION` will remove duplicates, making this query work for both a single record of friends, or the 2 record friendship you mention in the comment.  You shouldn't need the 2 record friendship though, because there is no new information being stored in the second record that you cannot get from only having one record.

Comment: thank you.  seems efficient. I assume this is for the single record friendship as I discussed above and not the 2 record friendship, right?   Also, where would you join a users table to pull usernames from.  On each select query?  Thanks again

Comment: @Brando you may join users table with the query above using it as a table. Just modify select portions as 1) SELECT FriendId as fID, 2) SELECT UserId as fID then join on users.id = fID

Comment: @Brando I have updated my answer to give you an idea of how to grab the friend's name, along with ID from an external table.

Comment: Thank you all extremely for this.  Slamming my head against the wall with this one and frustrating the lack of documentation out there.  I will give this a shot.  Thank you!!

Comment: Thank you @AdamWenger. One step away.  This query works, for a table that has the 2 record friendship method.  However, if it doesn't make sense to use that method in the first place, then we need a query to all the friendships for the single record friendship instead. I recently adjusted my friendship table to only insert one record per friendship instead of two...so what would that query look like?  This is close but it only pulls the friendships I initiated or that others initiated, but not both at the same time. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @Brando Did you try this query with your new method of only storing one record for a friend relationship? I'm looking at the query again, and I believe it will give you the results you desire.

Comment: Yes, I did.  Thank you. As mentioned it seems to only pull friendships I initiated or that others initiated, but not both at the same time.  In other words....if a member has 13 friendships (10 of which he initiated and 3 of where the friend initiated) this query will show either the 10 results or the 3 results but not the 13 friendships over all.  From what I am seeing anyway.  Thanks @AdamWenger in advance.

Comment: @Brando Please look at the SQL Fiddle link I added to my answer.  I set up test User and Friendship tables, and the query in my answer provides all friendships for me, whether my Id (1) is in the FriendId or UserId column in the Friend table.

Comment: JUST GOT IT !!!  I made a small edit including the "f." to the userID and FriendId in the second part of the query,.  That seemed to do it!! Thank you so so much!!