# Database schema to store friendship details

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I am creating an application where the user logs in with her twitter/facebook/foursquare accounts sequentially, and fetches all the IDs and other details of the people she is following (or has them in her list as friends)

I have referred to these questions:

- [friendship database schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910134/friendship-database-schema)
- [Single Row Friendship Database Schema with getting...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12984497/single-row-friendship-database-schema-with-getting-userid-from-one-column-or-the)

But the only thing is, the above designs focus on 'friendship' model, while I'd want to base the system on 'follow' model.
In 'friendship' model, both the users add/confirm each other, while in 'follow' model, one user can follow another, without confirmation.

I could go ahead with a design where one table stores all the users of my app, and the other stores all the people that they follow along with other information, but since I am not very good with database design, I am concerned about the scenario when I end up duplicating a lot of rows.
For example:

- If Kathy follows Ana on some network, Steve follows Ana on some other network, I end up having two rows for Ana, depicting relationship with these two users. Is this fine?
- What if on different networks, Ana and Steve follow each other? Is having two rows for this relationship avoidable?
- On some network Steve follows Kathy, that will again have one row for their relation. Is this okay?
- Ana is likely to be a friend of Kathy on more than one social network (twitter+facebook), and I'd have to have two rows for storing different information of these two networks for the same person Ana. Is this fine?

I am not a pro when it comes to database design, and normally get them designed from db guys, but this time its my personal app, so I have less idea what's good and what's not.

This system is likely to become pretty large as different users end up adding more than one of their social network accounts. I'll be using LAMP in the beginning, and am basically concerned about complexity that a bad database design may increase.

Any suggestions or ideas about the schema are deeply welcomed.
Just comment if any more information is required.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the database to be normalized, you would need a separate line for each relationship. If you stored all relationships, let's say by the putting the followers id in a field called followerID, then if that record is deleted based on one follower, all followers get deleted. So yes, multiple records are a good idea.

What you could also do is set up a relationship table based like Follow_Relationships using the primary keys of the followed and the follower and whatever other pertinent information you would require. That way, you could just perform a join on the two tables.

I hope this helps!

Comment: That pretty much helps, although I will have to grill my knowledge of joins once again :P

Answer (score 1):

As there are a limited number of social networks, it wouldn't be *too* wasteful to have relationships in different networks as a flag in a single relation.

For example, if Steve and Ana are connected in any network, the relationship could be represented in a single row with addition columns to denote the different follow/friend relationships. If you have a limited number of users, this might be acceptable for ease of use with a tradeoff in efficiency of design.

For a large database, proper relations are advised and I would say you'd need a distinct record for each relationship with each user. If you have a scenario where two users follow each other, I suppose you could have a 'isReciprocal' flag against a single record between two users:

```
User1|User2|isReciprocal
Steve|Kathy|1
```

Where when isReciprocal = 1, they follow each other, and if 0, Steve follows Kathy, but Kathy doesn't follow Steve.

If the relationship changes (Steve unfollows Kathy, Kathy starts following Steve), that relationship could be changed so that Kathy is User1, and Steve is User2. Hope that is clear.

Ultimately though design is a scale issue. Some very inefficient designs are perfectly fine if you have, say, less than 10000 users and updates are infrequent. If you're getting into tens/hundreds of thousands of records and relationships, updated constantly, making the design more efficient is very advisable.

Often a small and fast solution can be overly-designed, and I think in these situations unnormalised data is acceptable for the ease of use you get as a result.

Comment: I do get your `isReciprocal` concept. thanks! by 10,000 users you mean total 10000 records? if you mean 10k users and then their different friends, then it is going to become huge. But yes, I should not falling for premature optimization and start building, if performance drops, will look for other options

Comment: I'd say 10,000 users (and assume a couple of hundred thousand relational records), before you start seeing a real impact of inefficient design - or rather, a real benefit of using a more efficient design instead! 

If you anticipate it becoming very large, I'd go for the efficient design from the offset. Having to translate data to a more relational schema at some point in the future would be a massive job.

Comment: That `efficient` design is what I am after, any suggestions what would be one efficient one?

Comment: Again, it's a difficult call but if you want something that can fully handle very large data sets, I'd go for a fully-relational and normalised solution. That generally means lots of tables to store the normalised permutations of the data (e.g. different relationships between users), but also saves significant space by only querying for the data needed in any given query, generally making them faster, and taking up less disk space.